# making telegram bot without HTTPS

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a bot to connect to my web host and access database and interact with PHP.
But I searched a lot and find out that I need to have SSL certificate .Is there any way to set up a bot without Having SSl ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetUpdates` method is for debugging. You need to use Telegram `Webhook` and yes you must have an SSL certificate. But if you don't want to buy a paid certificate, you can use the [Cloud Flare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) for free. In Cloud Flare `'Flexible SSL'` service you do not need to install any certificate on the server side and simply (with changing name servers) make your website as SSL that telegram accepts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use long polling with `getUpdates`.  https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates

Comment: Hi, do you know if the getUpdates method can be used without HTTPS? I have read on the Telegram API doc that "All queries to the Telegram Bot API must be served over HTTPS"